# Vue.js 2 v-for loop doesn't get array element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-for

I'm trying to check if an element is an Array.  If true then print the elements of the array, else print the element.

My code does not print the element and I don't know where there is a problem.

**HTML**:

```
<div>
<ul>
<li v-for="(value, i) in testData" :key="i">
<template v-if="Array.isArray(value)">
<div v-for="(element, ind) in value" :key="ind">{‌{ element }}</div>
</template>
<template v-else> {‌{ value }} </template>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**Script**:

```
export default {   
data() {
return {
testData: {
id: 1,
name: "MyTest",            
data: [1,0.5,5,8],
},}}
```

**MyOtput**:

```
{‌{ value }}
{‌{ value }}
{‌{ element }}
{‌{ element }}
{‌{ element }}
{‌{ element }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first curly brace `{‌{` of each interpolation expression in your post has an extra, invisible unicode character.  I'm not sure how you created that but it causes the problem.

When copy-pasting the braces `{‌{` into this [Unicode text analyzer](https://www.fontspace.com/unicode/analyzer#e=e-KAjHs) it shows that there are 3 characters:

- `{` =     `U+007B`    `LEFT CURLY BRACKET`
- =     `U+200C`    `ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER`   ❌ Should not be here
- `{` =     `U+007B`    `LEFT CURLY BRACKET`

With correct braces, your code does work:

```js
new Vue({
el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      testData: {
        id: 1,
        name: "MyTest",            
        data: [1,0.5,5,8]
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(value, i) in testData" :key="i">
      <template v-if="Array.isArray(value)">
        <div v-for="(element, ind) in value" :key="ind">{{ element }}</div>
      </template>
      <template v-else>{{ value }}</template>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```